# Searching answers that you gave

Tags: support, search

According to stack exchange meta, to search one of your answers, you have to use the search bar as follow:

`User: my_username is:answer keyword_of_the_answer_that_you_need`

But that only shows me answers and comments with my user name mentioned inside.

Is there any way to search only for my own answers?

Comment: You may want to look at the [search FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for more details.  If by 'keyword' you mean tag, enclose it in square brackets, id "user:me is:a [python]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for your own answers include `user:me` in your search terms, or a specific user number like `user:19307` or `user:66870`; not the username.

Comment: Yes, worked, thanks